# Flutter: How to get the loudness of audio?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, package, audio-recording

I wonder that, in Flutter(Android), is there any way to extract the loudness from an audio file, or display the loudness while recording voice through microphone? What packages may be of some help? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to increase the sound, while playing an audio file?
what do you mean by displaying the loudness?

Comment: I mean, get the intensify of the sound, calculate how many dBs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use https://pub.dev/packages/noise_meter. It can record voice and detect its decibel. It's a great package.